# Bluetooth в ios эмуляторе

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, bluetooth

Есть устройство которое общается с ios приложением по bluetooth и отправляет некоторые данные.

Приложение разрабатывается на яблочном ноуте в XCode(Obj-C).

При запуске отладке стартует эмулятор, выбран iPhone 6s Plus / iOS 9.3

Собственно вопрос. Как научить эмулятор видеть мое устройств? Сам протокол взаимодействия реализован и если собрать приложение и закинуть на телефон, все будет работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Боюсь что Симулятор не может работать с блютузом. Для теста прийдется запускать на двух реальных девайсах сразу.